# Can't Edit Tile Map Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, xcode8

i cant find the editor bar of the Tile MAp and when i click of editor i cant select the edit tile map (i already clicked done), i searched ovreall but i cant find anything about this
[image: xcode snippet]

[image]

Comment: @Ivan what code ? the problem is with xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a stupid one , after clicking on "done", clicking on the tile map twice will solve the problem